# SKLabel fade away animation in swift

Tags: swift

I was wondering if someone could show me how to do the following. I created a game using sprite kit. The game starts and it will show the title screen and a label that says "tap to start". What I would like to happen is, when the user taps the screen, instead of the labels suddenly disappearing, I would like it to disappear over 2 seconds. Meaning, you can see the label disappear and fading away to alpha 0. I only have experience using UIKit, so sprite kit is new territory for me. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an SKAction, here's an example:

```
let fadeAction = SKAction.fadeAlphaTo(0, duration: 2.0)
```

Now you've got your action you can use your `SKLabelNode` to run it.

```
label.runAction(fadeAction)
```

If you're new to SpriteKit I would recommend you take a look at this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/42699/spritekit-tutorial-for-beginners

Comment: Thank you ! I appreciate it. I've been through Ray's tutorials and their great. I'm getting along well with sprite kit, just now and then there are things I don't fully understand. Really appreciate the help. Have a good day !

Answer (score 1):

```
  let fadeAway = SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(2.0)
  let removeNode = SKAction.removeFromParent()
  let sequence = SKAction.sequence([fadeAway, removeNode])
  label.runAction(sequence)
```